# Is a "would" required in this sentence

Tags: grammar, register

> Being a responsible man, arriving half an hour late would surely surprise his wife. But then he thought that it'd be funnier if he waited a couple of hours.

Vs.

> Being a responsible man, **he** would surely surprise his wife if he arrived half an hour late. But then he thought that it'd be funnier if **he'd** waited a couple of hours.

First, I would like to know if after the participial phrase "Being a responsible man", one should use the noun it modifies, *he*?

Moreover, the first sentence seems lacks a subject.

Second, whether  "would" is necessary before "waited" or not or both are possible depending on the sentence.

Actually these sentences are two corrections by seemingly two English-speakers for a post by a non-native speaker.

Comment: @TRomano I completed the question. I also didn't get what is funny, or its about me or the man in story.

Comment: Why not use the same basic question twice, rather than introducing a different sentence?  You are introducing unnecessary variables.

Comment: @TRomano if you mean *arrive* instead of *got up* I modified it. I didn't notice that.

Comment: If you use *'d waited*, the *'d* will be understood as *had*, not *would*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. How do you distinguish them?

Comment: @Ahmad A verb after the modal verb *would* never is in its past participle form.

Answer (score 2):

Especially since the sentence uses informal contractions (**it'd**) it could say:

> **Him** being a responsible man, it would surely surprise his wife if he
>   was half an hour late.

Whether to use past perfect depends on whether the man is looking forward to looking back upon the joke or is enjoying it now:

If would be funnier if he had waited...

It would be funnier if he waited...

Comment: But if it was *Being a responsible man*, it'd better the next clause begins with "He" right?

Comment: Questions of register aside (raised by the use of informal contractions), yes, the main clause should begin with the subject the participle phrase is modifying, **he** or "Mister Jones" or whatever.